# To add routerlink to an element dynamically from type script code in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, angular2-directives, routerlink

In my Angular application I came across a scenario in which I have to show an activity history for a user as in Facebook's activity log.

The activity templates may be of different types like:

1. **KLM** creates subOrder **10463** from Order **2569**
2. **XYZ** deleted subOrder **1046**
3. **ABC** commented on Order **2569**

and so on.

The bold text will be a link which navigates the user to the user's corresponding profile or particular `subOrder` or `Order`.

In the TypeScript file I created the link for users/actors like KLM, ABC or XYZ as follows:

```js
const tempActorLink = '<a href=/user-profile/' + history.actorId + '/' + history.actorName + '>' + history.actorName + '</a>';
```

Then I replace the `{actor}` string in `history` with the created link as follows:

```js
history.activity = history.activity.replace('{actor}', tempActorLink);
```

I did the same when creating `Order` and `subOrder` links.

I used `innerHTML` to add it to the DOM as shown below:

```html
<span innerHTML="{{history.activity}}"></span>
```

Due to the use of `href` the page reloads, which is undesirable.

I tried to use the `routerLink` directive as shown in the TypeScript code below:

```js
const tempActorLink = '<a [router-link]=\"[\'/user-profile/' + history.actorId + '/' + history.actorName + '\']\">' + history.actorName + '</a>';
```

I can't see the `routerLink` directive in the created DOM code.

Please help me out to dynamically add the links in the DOM with the `routerLink` directive or some other approach that has the desired effect.

Comment: You can't add anything Angular-specific to a template dynamically. The only way to do that is to create and compile a component that contains that markup in the template at runtime. What you can do is to use `querySelector(...)` to query the dynamically added HTML, add a click handler `addEventListener(...)` and assign a callback that calls `this.router.navigate(...)`

Comment: you cannot add the routerlink directive using this way as innerhtml , you need to follow the way as @GünterZöchbauer pointed out